# Erro ao instalar o npm

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

Uso o Linux Mint 19, há algum tempo, instalei o npm, o nodejs, bootstrap, assim como o Jquery, o Popper.js, etc. Porém, decidi apagar a pasta em que tinha instalado tais arquivos, para começar de novo. Agora, quando tento instalar novamente o npm na pasta, obtenho o seguinte erro:

---

Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que
você solicitou uma situação impossível ou, se você está usando a
distribuição instável, que alguns pacotes requeridos não foram
criados ainda ou foram retirados da "Incoming".
A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 npm : Depende: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) mas não será instalado
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.

---

Obs: estou usando o comando "sudo apt-get install npm"
O que devo fazer para resolver?

Comment: Então Gabriel, você está com pacotes quebrados, tenta: `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg --configure -a` obs: não estou com tempo de escrever uma resposta agora, mas qualquer coisa vai dando feedback se funcionou :)

Comment: Apareceu a mensagem: Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:
  eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp fastjar jarwrapper
  libcommons-httpclient-java libeasymock-java libecj-java
  libfelix-bundlerepository-java libfelix-gogo-command-java
  libfelix-gogo-shell-java libicu4j-49-java libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjetty9-java liblucene2-java libobjenesis-java libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni
  libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat8-java
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 sat4j
Utilize 'sudo apt autoremove' para os remover.

Comment: Utilizei o comando 'sudo apt autoremove' e ele removeu os arquivos citados, porém, o problema na hora da instalação do npm ainda persiste.

Comment: Ainda é a mesma mensagem de erro na instalação?

Comment: Tenta remover e adicionar o `nodejs` de novo.

Comment: Nodejs e npm é o que você instalar para posteriormente instalar jQuery, bootstrap e Popper.js dentro de um projeto, logo se não conseguiu instalar o nodejs não vejo como iria instalar o "npm na pasta", npm deveria ser global.

Comment: Removi e reinstalei o nodejs globalmente, mas ainda está dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Teve alguma solução? Estou tendo o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Galera o jeito mais fácil que eu encontrei para instalar o nodejs no Ubuntu foi o nvm. E não é recomendado o uso do comando:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Tentem este:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
nvm install v16.4.0
npm i npm -g
```

Espero que ajude.

FONTE: https://medium.com/collabcode/como-instalar-node-js-no-linux-corretamente-ubuntu-debian-elementary-os-729fb4c92f2d